# Make lightbox work even before all images are loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using [Featherlite](http://noelboss.github.io/featherlight/) as my lightbox and my problem is, I have a lot of images (thumbnails) to load on my page and when it's loading and I click one of the loaded image, the lightbox doesn't work. Therefore, it will go to the jpeg file on to the other page instead of a modal window.

How can I make my lightbox even after all the images are all loaded. By the way, I'm putting this on my WordPress but I don't want to use a plugin. Also I'm using FoundationPress.

Here's the code I use to initiate my lightbox

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a.gallery').featherlight({
    targetAttr: 'href'
  });
});
```

I have images loaded script but I'm using it on my masonry. How can I put the lightbox scripts inside the images loaded plugin?

```
(function() {

// Main content container
var $container = $('.grid');

var $grid = $('.grid').masonry({
  // options
  columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  percentPosition: true

});

// layout Masonry after each image loads
$grid.imagesLoaded().progress( function() {
  $grid.masonry('layout');
});

// Infinite Scroll
$container.infinitescroll({

    navSelector  : '.pagination',    // selector for the paged navigation 
    nextSelector : '.pagination a.next',  // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
    itemSelector : '.grid-item',     // selector for all items you'll retrieve
    loading: {
            msg: null,
            msgText: '<i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin"></i>',
            finishedMsg: '<i class="fa fa-check"></i>',
            img: null
      }
    },


    // Trigger Masonry as a callback
    function( newElements ) {
        // hide new items while they are loading
        var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });
        // ensure that images load before adding to masonry layout
        $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
            // show elems now they're ready
            $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
            $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true );
        });

});

})();
```

Comment: can  you show some more code

Comment: Actually that is all. I have other codes but it's not related to the lightbox. For example I have masonrly plugin and images loaded plugin but I use that on a different page. But they are in one scripts.js. Does that help?

Comment: If it is not working there might be a JavaScript error. Did you check the console in your web browser?

Comment: Actually it works, but just after all the images are loaded. I have so many thumbnails. After all the thumbnails are loaded, it works. But before all the images are loaded, it doesn't. Here the link. Click the image on the bottom of the page before all the images are loaded and you'll see what I mean. http://ableslayer.com/photo/saigon. Also, please don't look around the site as it's currently under maintenance :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure if I understood correctly what solution you would like, but you could use

https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded

which is specifically made for use cases like masonry plugin layouts,
to check if all images have finished loading and then execute functions / other scripts.

For example:

```
$('#your-container').imagesLoaded( {
  },
  function() {
    $('a.gallery').featherlight({
      targetAttr: 'href'
    });
  }
);
```

Hope this helps a bit?

Comment: I will try this. What I want to do is to be able to click on the thumbnail and the lightbox will work even before all the images are loading. The thing is, I think, it's loading the images first before the script and therefore, no script before the images are all loaded. So the lightbox won't work. Here's my page http://ableslayer.com/photo/saigon

Comment: Btw, I have an imagesloaded script that I use for my masonry. How can I intergrate that to my lightbox? I updated my scripts above.

Comment: No, that is the correct order: let the images load, then fire script last. Scripts always at the bottom. With the infinite scroll and lightbox I'll need to come back to you.

Comment: Is it all working now? Seems like it. What else is not working right for you?

Comment: No, still not working. Image still goes to a new page instead of lightbox when images aren't loaded. Have you tried in incognito mode? Maybe your browser cached all the images already and it's already loaded when you click an image. I know that I have a lot of images in the page. If I use lazy loader, will that help me? I just want to solve the mystery. Surely there's a solution to that.